# programmatically UIScrollView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

i am new to IOS. i tried 8 UItext-field add to UIScrollView.
My code like this :-

```
 City=[[UITextField alloc]init];
    City.frame=CGRectMake(45, 150, 221, 30);
    [self.view addSubview:City];
    City.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    City.placeholder=@"Email";
    [City setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:20]];
    //[Username setTextAlignment:UITextBor];
    City.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor yellowColor]CGColor];
    City.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
    [City setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
same as 
city1=[[UITextField alloc]init];
City1.frame=CGRectMake(45, 195, 221, 30);

  |
  |
  |
  |
city8=[[UITextField alloc]init];
city8.frame=CGRectMake(45, 355, 221, 30);
```

Jest I create 8textFileds now all are add to UIScrollview.

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [UIScrollView alloc];
    scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 105, 221, 355)];

    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;

    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scroll.scrollsToTop = NO;
    scroll.delegate = self;             //say "NO" to disable scroll
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
    [scroll addSubview:City];
    [scroll addSubview:City1];
     |
     |
    [scroll addSubview:City8];
```

I need only UITextField with UIScrollView.First crated UITextField and then Create ScrollView and add both but my textFileds are not adding Scroll

Pleae give me any idea,And Please tell me what wrong in my code

Comment: Don't give your variables capitalised names

Comment: try to set contentSize for scroll view

Comment: @AndreyChernukha removed capitalised name but no luck

Comment: make content size of your scroll view

Comment: @karthikeyan Please lock my code

Comment: set like this           self.scrView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(960, 0);

Answer (score 1):

Remove this code and check

```
[self.view addSubview:City];
```

place this code after adding all textfields in scrollview.

```
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

It may help you.

Comment: thanks for reply i tried as you said but no luck Please give me any idea

Comment: Have you set the content size for scrollview.

Comment: i set content size like this scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 105, 221, 355)];

Comment: scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent);

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
 UIScrollView *scroll ;
        scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    //set your frame according to your viewframe or text field frame.here give width and height of scrolling
    scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width+100,self.view.frame.size.height+100);
        scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
       self.scrView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
        self.scrView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 UIScrollView *scroll = [UIScrollView alloc];
    scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scroll.scrollsToTop = NO;
    scroll.delegate = self;             //say "NO" to disable scroll
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*8,0);

 UITextField*City=[[UITextField alloc]init];
    City.frame=CGRectMake(45, 150, 221, 30);
    City.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    City.placeholder=@"Email";
    [City setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:20]];
    //[Username setTextAlignment:UITextBor];
    City.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor yellowColor]CGColor];
    City.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
    [City setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];

UITextField*city1=[[UITextField alloc]init];
    city1.frame=CGRectMake(45, 195, 221, 30);
    city1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    city1.placeholder=@"Email1";
    UITextField*city8=[[UITextField alloc]init];
    city8.frame=CGRectMake(45, 355, 221, 30);
    [scroll addSubview:City];
    [scroll addSubview:city1];
    [scroll addSubview:city8];
   [self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `UITextField's` to `UIScrollView` than no need to add it `self.view`.
So remove statement that adds `UITextField's` to `self.view`. though it is not the problem you asked but it is unnecessary to add those textfields in view.

so remove all --> `[self.view addSubview:City];`

As far as your problem concern, you did everything right except one thing and that is "increasing content size" of your `UIScrollView`. that you can increase as follows

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(Width,height);
```

Width & Height you can set according to your requirement.

for more please refer [UIScrollView reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize)

Answer (score 0):

```
City=[[UITextField alloc]init];
   City.frame=CGRectMake(45, 150, 221, 30);
    [self.view addSubview:City];//----------------> Please remove this line
    City.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    City.placeholder=@"Email";
    [City setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:20]];
    //[Username setTextAlignment:UITextBor];
    City.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor yellowColor]CGColor];
    City.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
    [City setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];
same as 
city1=[[UITextField alloc]init];
City1.frame=CGRectMake(45, 195, 221, 30);

  |
  |
  |
  |
city8=[[UITextField alloc]init];
city8.frame=CGRectMake(45, 355, 221, 30);
```

After creating all the textfield (Eight Text fields) then create the ScrollView

```
//UIScrollView *scroll = [UIScrollView alloc]; //---------------> No Need this line
    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 105, 221, 355)];

    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES; //---------------->>> Do you need paging ? Other wise set NO

    scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scroll.scrollsToTop = NO;
    scroll.delegate = self;             //say "NO" to disable scroll
    [scroll addSubview:City];
    [scroll addSubview:City1];
     |
     |
    [scroll addSubview:City8];
```

After adding all text field as the sub view of your scroll view we must place the scroll view to your parent View So please add the following code

```
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

Now everything is ok,But still now your scroll view is not scrollable because we not set a scroll content size,To do this

**1) Your text field is height 30 and the space between two text field is 15 so total 45
    you have 8 Text field Toatl = 360**

**2) Your starting textfield Y Axis is 150 not Zero so we need to add 360 + 150 = 510**

**3) Your scroll view Width and Textfield width are common = 221**

```
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(510,221);
```

Now build it,All the best ,Keep coding :)